# Display the name of the value in my database for each option

Tags: javascript, php, html

i don't know how to explain well, but i want to display the name of the choice i made, and the names are in the database. To understand, here is my select  :

```
 <select name="options[1][]" id="perso_1" class="multiselect
 required-entry product-custom-option" title="" 
 onchange="displayCondition()">
     <option value="0" disabled>Testing</option>
     <option value="1">Test1</option>
     <option value="2">Test2</option> 
</select>
```

Here is the function to display a message under the choice :

```
function displayCondition() {
condition = new Array("", 
    "<div class='bordure'><?php echo $row['perso_name']; ?></div>", 

    "<div class='bordure'><?php echo $row['perso_name']; ?></div>", 

    "<div class='bordure'></div>"                   
    );
var getsel = document.getElementById('perso_1').value;
document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = condition[getsel];
```

}

And the variables :

```
$getperso = "SELECT * FROM perso";
$persoresult = mysqli_query($connection, $getperso) or die("Erro!: " . mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($persoresult)
```

The code is working, but it only display the name of the first "perso_name" and i don't know how to change to the second one, maybe something like "perso_name(2)" or i don't know..

If you could help me, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Add a while into your code without the while condition the query will only run once.Thats why it only display the name of the first person. Try do something like this

```
if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($getperso)) > 0)
{
    $getperso = mysqli_query($getperso)or die(mysqli_error());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getperso))
    {
        echo $row['perso_name'];
echo "</br>;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But it will display the name of every person in a echo, isn't ? I want this to be able to display perso_name of row 1 in the first echo, and perso_name of row 2 in the second one

Comment: refer edited one ...it should make the second person at the second row

Comment: Well, sadly, it's still not solving my problem, because what i need is to display "perso_name 1" in the first echo, "perso_name 2" in the second, but it's not suiting my script, because if i follow this script, i would have to copy/paste the whole script in each echo, and it would display every names when the user choose something in the <select>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in by the following code :

```
<?php $getperso = "SELECT * FROM perso"; ?>
<select name="options[1][]" id="perso_1" class="multiselect
required-entry product-custom-option" title="" 
onchange="displayCondition(this.value)">
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($getperso)) > 0)
{
   $getperso = mysqli_query($getperso)or die(mysqli_error());
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getperso))
   { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['perso_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['perso_name']; ?></option>
   <?php }
} ?>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function displayCondition(value) {
     document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = "<div class='bordure'>"+ value +"
     </div>";
  }
```

I think this might resolve your issue. All the best.